# How to store multiple files under the same model attribute in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to store multiple files in the same Django model attribute.
The attribute I currently have:

```
    class Request_tab(models.Model):
    
         attachments= models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to=get_upload_path)
    
    def get_upload_path(instance,filename):
         return "{procurement_id}/{file}".format(procurement_id=instance.procurement_id,file=filename)
```

I am using Postman to test my APIs and using serializers for JSON data conversion and MySQL as database.
Is there a way to do this without the serializers generating a problem?

Comment: Please read the how to ask topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest using an M2M field from Request_tab model to Attachment model.

```
class Request_tab(models.Model):
    attachments=models.ManyToManyField(Attachment)

class Attachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried implementing this but Postman generated an error saying{
    "attachments": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received InMemoryUploadedFile."
    ]
}

Comment: Because attachments is expecting the id of the attachment files and not the files itself , edit your serializers .

Comment: I could not understand how to edit the serializers,  should I pass data relevant to the pk id? The Request_tab has many attributes and they are posted to the backend through a form. I can isolate the serializer for attachments but how to send a pk value?

Comment: attachement model has a file Field file , you have to create this model first by sending InMemoryUploadedFile.. And then add the attachment to the Request_tab model .. with the id of created attachment by request_tab_object.attachments.add(attachment)

Comment: This helped me a lot, I can now save multiple files in the destination directory but one at a time, thus the attribute holds only one file for a particular instance and while making a get call only one file shows.

Comment: Its a many to many field , thus it points to multiple files in Attachment Model. .First upload files to Attachment model , after adding all files , you can do request_tab_object.attachments.add(*[files_array])

Comment: Pleases upvote and accept answer if helped @AkshitaGupta

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Let's rename `Request_tab` to `RequestTab` for readability.
Add this model

```
class Attachment(models.Model):  # singular
    file = models.FileField..............
    request_tab = models.ForiegnKey('RequestTab', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attachments')  # quotes because it's below
```

Now, every `RequestTab` object has .attachments which is a many related manager.

Think of it as `attachment.requesttab` and `requesttab.attachments`

Comment: Thank you for your reply I tried implementing it but got the errors: Reverse accessor for 'Attachment.request_tab' clashes with field name 'Request_tab.attachments'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Request_tab.attachments', or add/change a related_name argument to definition for field 'Attachment.request_tab'.                                                Reverse query name for 'Attachment.request_tab' clashes with field name 'Request_tab.attachments'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Request_tab.attachments', or add/change a related_name argument to definition for field 'Attachment.request_tab'.